# Programatically deploy Lambda@Edge triggered by 'viewer-request' Cloudfront event

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront, aws-lambda-edge

I've been trying to deploy on AWS a Lambda Function as Lambda@Edge that is been
triggered by the Cloudfront event `viewer-request`.

In this Lambda@Edge function I would like to validate the api key I get in the
request header `Authorization`.

I need to run the function on the `viewer-request` because I cannot cache the
validation of the key since it can be revoked.

This is the diagram of the Cloudfront events:
[image: event diagram]

I managed to deploy a Lambda@Edge function manually from the AWS Console, but
now I would like do it programmatically.

I first tried using Serverless Framework. Serverless Framework
[supports Lambda@Edge](https://www.serverless.com/blog/lambda-at-edge-support-added)
but it doesn't support to attach the Lambda@Edge to an already deployed
Cloudfront distribution.

I found a plugin that does that [`serverless-lambda-edge-pre-existing-cloudfront`](https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-lambda-edge-pre-existing-cloudfront)

After deploying the serverless lambda function, if I check the Cloudfront
distribution behaviour, I found the Lambda@Edge correctly configured and
attached to the correct event `viewer-request`.

However when I call the Cloudfront URL from the browser (or Postman) I am
getting a 503 Error:

```
503 ERROR
The request could not be satisfied.
The Lambda function associated with the CloudFront distribution is invalid or doesn't have the required permissions. We can't connect to the server for this app or website at this time. There might be too much traffic or a configuration error. Try again later, or contact the app or website owner.
If you provide content to customers through CloudFront, you can find steps to troubleshoot and help prevent this error by reviewing the CloudFront documentation.
Generated by cloudfront (CloudFront)
Request ID: **************************************
```

Then I also tried to deploy the Cloudfront distribution together with the Lambda
with the Serverless Framework.

Then I also tried to deploy the Cloudfront distribution and the Lambda@Edge with
Terraform, first trying to associate the Lambda to the Cloudfront event, and
then also trying to deploy all together.

In all cases I am getting always the same error 503.

> NOTE: If I select the event `origin-request` it doesn't give me the error.

The only way I managed to make it work is with the AWS Console. Going to the

```
Lambda Function > Versions > (Select last version) > Add trigger >
Select Cloudfront trigger > Configure new CloudFront trigger >
Select distribution > CloudFront event (viewer-request) >
Select **"Confirm deploy to Lambda@Edge"**
```

[image: add trigger]

This is the most important part: Selecting **"Confirm deploy to Lambda@Edge"**

Only by selecting this, everything works.

So I tried to use AWS CLI to add the trigger and to confirm to deploy to
Lambda@Edge.

However I found that is still not supported:
[https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cloudformation-coverage-roadmap/issues/953]

So I am thinking that since there is no API for this feature it cannot be done,
not with Serverless, nor with Terraform or any other SDK.

I've been testing with a Lambda function that doesn't modify anything it just log the event. This is the code:

```js
exports.handler = (event, _context, callback) => {
  console.log('EVENT', event);
  const request = event.Records[0].cf.request;
  console.log('REQUEST', request);
  callback(null, request);
}
```

These are the permission I gave to the Lambda with terraform syntax. I did the same also for Serverless:

```
data aws_iam_policy_document assume_role {
  statement {
    effect = "Allow"
    principals {
      type = "Service"
      identifiers = [
        "lambda.amazonaws.com",
        "edgelambda.amazonaws.com"
      ]
    }
    actions = ["sts:AssumeRole"]
  }
}

resource aws_iam_role iam_for_lambda {
  name               = "new_cloudfront_access_lambda"
  assume_role_policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.assume_role.json
  inline_policy {
    name = "my_inline_policy"
    policy = jsonencode({
      Version = "2012-10-17"
      Statement = [
        {
          Action   = [
            "lambda:InvokeFunction",
            "lambda:GetFunction",
            "lambda:EnableReplication*",
            "iam:CreateServiceLinkedRole",
            "cloudfront:UpdateDistribution",
          ]
          Effect   = "Allow"
          Resource = "*"
        },
      ]
    })
  }
}
```

## My final question is

Does anybody ever succeeded to **programmatically** deploy a lambda function to
Lambda@Edge as `viewer-request` for a Cloudfront distribution?

Comment: *"So I am thinking that since there is no API for this feature it cannot be done, not with Serverless, nor with Terraform or any other SDK."* - if the UI does it then there is an API then you can do it as well. The mentioned GitHub issue seems to be plain wrong since this will not be an event source mapping. I think more likely you are missing some permissions: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-edge-permissions.html - check e.g. the permissions section of the UI-associated lambda.

Comment: What role have you configured your lambda to use and what does its trust relationship look like? Do you allow both "lambda" and "edgelambda" to assume it?

Comment: I have updated the question with the permission I used. It would be amazing to have a script that works.

Comment: If "Add a trigger" is not an event source mapping, then what is the API that does this?

Comment: The API is CreateDistribution / UpdateDistribution: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/latest/APIReference/API_CreateDistribution.html => https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/latest/APIReference/API_DefaultCacheBehavior.html => https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/latest/APIReference/API_LambdaFunctionAssociations.html => https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/latest/APIReference/API_LambdaFunctionAssociation.html - make sure you are adding a specific function version arn and not $LATEST.

Comment: And this works without any problems in CDK and therefore in CFN as well, even without custom resources.

Comment: The API CreateDistribution or UpdateDistribution is the one I used in the post. This associate the Lambda Function in the `default_cache_behavior.function_association` but then it gives the 503 error. This happen even if you do it manually from the AWS Console. To make it work, the only way is to add the trigger from the Lambda Version itself. That is why I am looking for the API the add the trigger and not the Update/CreateDistribution.

Comment: It does not do anything else I would assume. If you really want to check open the network tab of your browser and inspect what API calls are sent and see which ones do what. I am pretty certain you do not need anything else.

Comment: I think it does add the permission to Cloudfront to replicate the Lambda. That is also probably why the error is 503, because the lambda are not replicated therfore Unavailable. But I don't know if that is true, or if it is possbile to add such permission to Cloudfront.

Comment: As my first link says CloudFront / Lambda@Edge uses service linked roles which should already exist. Check if they already exist.

Comment: Yes I know, that is why is weird. This is what I got from the network tab: `relations: 
{"servicePrincipal":"replicator.lambda.amazonaws.com","sid":["replicator.lambda.GetFunction"],"targetType":"aws/lambda","sourceType":"aws/cloudfront","sourceName":"XXXX","sourceUrl":"https://us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/v3/home?region=us-east-1#/distributions/XXXX","eventType":"viewer-request","pathPattern":"*","includeBody":false}"
source
: 
"arn:aws:cloudfront::XXX:distribution/XXX"
target
: 
"arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:XXXXXXXXX:function:lambda-funcion-name:58"
type
: 
"trigger"
`